# Properly configure JDK to run react native project

Tags: java, react-native

I am trying to run a react native app on a m1 mac, generated with react-native-starter-kit.[enter link description here](https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit). When I run the app with `npx react-native run-android`, I get the following error

> error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android
> SDK licenses using Android SDK Manager:
> "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses".

I tried to run the sdkmanager as following

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/   
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

I get an Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

Then I tried this JAVA_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/   
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

And it works, `All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...`

But when I run `npx react-native run-android` after that, I still have a licence error

```
Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android SDK licenses using Android SDK Manager
```

I have the feeling I am accepting the licenses in the wrong JDK. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you set up you development envoirement the correct way.

The [Official Guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) explains it step by step.

For you paragraph 2 (Install the Android SDK) should be helpful